# Создание страницы HTML с размерами для печати

Tags: print, html

Всем привет, доброго времени суток. Есть документ (страница сайта), которому выпала честь печататься помногу раз. Но не могу понять, какие размеру у страницы A4 в пикселях для печати. Ширина примерная, мне кажется, 850 пиксилей, но могу быть не прав.

1. Подскажите, размеры страницы, в пикселях, для печати.
2. Еще интересует в винде и в линуксе они одинаковые, и при разных разрешениях, от чего зависит?
3. Как при переходе к нужной странице сделать печать автоматически? (Без дополнительных нажатий и окон.)

Хотел бы услышать тех, кто много печатал страницы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<FORM>
<INPUT NAME="print" TYPE="button" VALUE=" Печать страницы " ONCLICK="varitext()">
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Begin
function varitext(text){
text=document
print(text)
}
// End -->
</SCRIPT>
</FORM>
```

Получится кнопочка печати страницы. Нужно придумать, как эмитировать нажатие на кнопку, и что бы самой кнопки не было видно. Размеры ~850*1240 (сам ищу).