# Печать страницы

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

Я написал PHP-страницу, хочу к ней прикрепить принтер, чтобы при нажатии кнопки, принтер эту страницу на бумаге отпечатал, скажите, как написать этот Javascript код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Создание страницы HTML с размерами для печати](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/24433/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-html-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) - аналогичная тема.